# Set working directory for function arguments

Tags: bash, bash-completion

My code is all located in the following directory on my computer /a/b/c/d/e/myCode. I got annoyed of typing make /a/b/c/d/e/myCode/project1 when I wanted to compile project1. To fix this I created a function in my bashrc that looks as follows:

```
function make_project { make /a/b/c/d/e/myCode/$1; }
```

Then I call it like this:

```
make_project project1
```

This works fine. The only problem with this is that I don't have autocompletion for project1. So if I have a project with a complicated name like my_complicatedly_named_project I will need to type the whole name in. Is there any way for bash to know that the arguments are directories in /a/b/c/d/e/myCode/ and it could autocomplete appropriately?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [compgen](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_compgen.htm) command can be used to generate and test completions and looking over the existing completions can provide some help generating new ones. You are after directories in a particular subtree so the following should work in bash:

```
function _make_project {
    COMPREPLY=( $(cd /a/b/c/d/myCode; compgen -A directory -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") );
}
```

This uses compgen to get directories that might complete the current argument, starting at the myCode subtree. To install this for your function you should use the `complete` command to associate this completion function with the bash function:

```
complete -F _make_project make_project
```

**Update**

To avoid having a space character appended to the completed work, when registering the completion function the *nospace* option can be provided. If this is combined with the *-S* option to compgen to append a suffix character then the completions can appear as directory names and it is possible to walk the subtree easily:

```
function _make_project {
    COMPREPLY=( $(cd /a/b/c/d/myCode; compgen -S / -A directory -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") );
}
complete -o nospace -F _make_project make_project
```

Comment: A small question, when I press tab now in autocompletes correctly but it adds a space afterwards. So if I want a subdirectory I have to click backspace and then /. Is there a way for the autocomplete not to add the space?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if bash can do this, but zsh can reasonably do this. To make this work in zsh, add this line to .zshrc:

```
fpath=(~/.zshcompletion $fpath)
```

Then create the file `~/.zshcompletion/_make_project`:

```
#compdef make_project

# _arguments "1: :(World)"

_make_project() {
    # Note: Do the following two lines mean anything?:
    local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
    typeset -A opt_args

    for dir in /a/b/c/d/e/myCode/*(/); do
        compadd "$@" "${dir/*\//}"
    done
}
```

Note: I know this isn't the answer you asked for, but since zsh has basically the same user interface as bash (with scripts usually being compatible), I figured it might be useful if there's not an easy bash solution.

Comment: You're welcome. This is quite similar to my case where I wanted to set some environment stuff based on which project I was working on, but the folder name was really the only important piece of data. So I figured out how to do this, and I hope I never have to figure it out again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a soft link for `myCode` directory.

```
ln -s /a/b/c/d/e/myCode/ ~/myCode
```

Modify your function to:

```
function make_project { make $1; }
```

I suppose typing an additional `myCode` will not hurt too much:

```
make_project ~/myCode/project_name
```

or just use `make`:

```
make ~/myCode/project_name
```

You can use autocomplete as well after typing `~/myCode/`